# Routes appear to exist in rake routes, unavailable when running spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-routing

I cannot seem to get the following worked out.

Spec: (spec/api/power_ups_spec.rb)

```
describe Api::PowerUpsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET power_ups" do
    it "returns all power-ups" do
      FactoryGirl.create :power_up, name: "Increase rate of take", description: "You gain points more quickly"
      FactoryGirl.create :power_up, name: "Decrease rate of give", description: "You lose points more slowly"

      get api_power_ups_path, {}, { "Accept" => "application/json" }

      expect(response.status).to eq 200

      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      power_up_names = body.map { |m| m["title"] }

      expect(power_up_names).to match_array(["Increase rate of take",
                                             "Decrease rate of give"])
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :power_ups, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Controller (app/controllers/api/power_up_controller.rb):

```
module Api
  class PowerUpsController < ApplicationController
    include ActionController::MimeResponds
    respond_to :json

    def index
      respond_with PowerUp.all
    end
  end
end
```

Rake Routes:

```
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
api_power_ups GET  /api/power_ups(.:format) api/power_ups#index
```

Error message on running spec:

```
 Failure/Error: get api_power_ups_path, {}, { "Accept" => "application/json" }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/api/power_ups", :controller=>"api/power_ups"}
```

Comment: Does it find the route if you change to `get api_power_ups_path, :format => :json`?

Comment: @infused,  The result is the same with the format=>json added to the error message `No route matches {:action=>"/api/power_ups", :controller=>"api/power_ups", :format=>:json}`

Comment: I assume the route works outside of RSpec.  Any reason not to use `get :index, :format => :json` in the spec?

Comment: @infused, thank you that worked.  The only reason it wasn't that way is that I saw it in a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get api_power_ups_path
```

this isn't how to use `get` in a controller spec.

In a controller-spec, you assume that the class-under-test in the controller... so you use `get` to call the actual method on the controller.

In this case the method is called `index` (ie, you have `def index`), so to activate the test you just call:

```
get :index
```

you use the path-helpers only when you are referring to other paths - eg where you get redirected to etc.